# How to add '.' to autocomplete suggestions in vim-latexsuite?

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex

In [vim-latexsuite](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) how do I make vim completing references and equations labels with `.` in them? For example, I call the equations by chapters:

```
label{eq:intro.x}
label{eq:physics.y}
```

But then, when trying to reference these equations, by hitting `Ctrl+n`, vim doesn't recognize the `.` part and it just completes the first word. Any solution?

Comment: I don't use this plugin so my solution might be totally out but does `:set iskeyword+=.` would solve your problem?

Comment: I think @statox may be right. Though, the completion you want works as expected withouth altering `iskeyword` in my plugin, [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), and I believe it also should work in [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took time to install vim-latexsuite and I can confirm that my comment was right: you simply have to execute `:set iskeyword+=.` to make completion work.

To avoid executing this function on each latex file you edit you can add the following line

```
setlocal iskeyword+=.
```

To the syntax file `.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim`